# What Mechanism does Xamarin Forms use to Detect Named controls in the code behind for Content Page and Content View?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to implement a control that derives from ControlTemplate but has the ability to detect controls in a code behind file. I need to understand how this works in Content Page/View

Answer (score 0):

There is a MSBuild task(s) called XamlG/UpdateDesignTimeXaml the generates the partial class that has the views that you have `x:Name` defined as global namespace class-level variables and thus generates the variable code of:

```
private global::Xamarin.Forms.Entry someEntryControl;
```

Then in that file's `InitializeComponent` method, the `FindByName` extension is used to assign the actual runtime instance to the previously defined variable by a string-based lookup by that variable's name:

```
someEntryControl = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.Entry>(this, "someEntryControl");
```

If you go down the rabbit hole of the XAML `FindByName` code dependancies, you will see that it basically performs a iteration of all the BindableObjects in that view's scope until it finds a matching name or returns `null`.